# Getting cp: target '{target}.yml' is not a directory when trying to use the cp command on windows

Tags: windows, macos, git-bash

I'm setting up a project that requires me to run a script to set up my docker environment. The thing is, I've successfully set this up on my mac and other's macs with no issues but when setting it up on other user's windows machine I keep running into this issue and I'm not sure how to resolve it as the command looks fine.

Here is the command that is run

```
[ -f docker/compose-volumes.yml ] || cp docker/compose-volumes.yml.sample docker/compose-volumes.yml; bash ./bin/compose-volumes.sh docker/compose-volumes.yml > docker/compose-volumes.built.yml
```

And here is the error it yields

```
cp: target 'docker/compose-volumes.yml' is not a directory
```

What I've already attempted is freshly pulling the project from git and running the command. It works immediately on mac's and fails immediately on windows.

Why would this command work totally fine on my mac but fail on a windows machine? Is there anything I can change so the command properly runs?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I found for this was the semi colon after the copy was causing an issue somehow on windows. For mac there was no effect. To fix I swapped out the `;` for `&&` and now it's working for both windows and mac